# Disconnecting the BE database to do compact

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm sure I'm just being blind here. I need to compact my BE data file, but the code fails because the initial file copy to backup the data file gives a permission denied.  I've seen several examples of compacting the MS Access Backend, but they all prediate their code with the statament 'Make sure all connections are disconnected".
    In my case both files are local.  There are no other users.  All forms have been closed.
The user is not a DBadmin type so a single button on the front end app to compact both would be ideal. 
Here is the compact code...

```
Err_Pos = 1
    If IsFormLoaded(frm_nm) Then
        DoCmd.Close acForm, frm_nm
    End If


    Fl_BE_Cnt_Str = Cnnt_str
    BE_Full_Nm_Str = Split(Split(Fl_BE_Cnt_Str, "Database=")(1), ";")(0)
    s_Pos = InStrRev(Fl_BE_Cnt_Str, "\")
    BE_DB_Name_Str = Right(Fl_BE_Cnt_Str, Len(Fl_BE_Cnt_Str) - s_Pos)
    s_Pos = InStrRev(BE_Full_Nm_Str, "\")
    BE_Path_Str = Left(BE_Full_Nm_Str, s_Pos)
    Tmp_BE_Hold_FNM_Str = BE_Path_Str & "Tmp_BE.accdb"

Err_Pos = 5

   're-map current table links to empty DB with same table Structure
    For Each T_Def In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If InStr(T_Def.Name, "MSys") = 0 Then
            T_Def.Connect = ";Database=" & BE_Path_Str & "MPD_BEStruct.accdb"
            T_Def.RefreshLink
        End If


    Next T_Def

 Err_Pos = 10
    'Backup
    s_Pos = InStrRev(BE_DB_Name_Str, ".")
    BkUp_FNMN_Str = Left(BE_DB_Name_Str, s_Pos) & ".BAK"
Err_Pos = 15
    ' remove  possible left over backup
    Kill BE_Path_Str & BkUp_FNMN_Str
    On Error GoTo Err_BE_Compact
Err_Pos = 20

    FileCopy BE_Full_Nm_Str, BE_Path_Str & BkUp_FNMN_Str
    'Compact
    DBEngine.CompactDatabase BE_Full_Nm_Str, Tmp_BE_Hold_FNM_Str
 Err_Pos = 25
    'Delete Uncompacted Version
    Kill BE_Full_Nm_Str
 Err_Pos = 30

    'Rename Compacted Version
    Name Tmp_BE_Hold_FNM_Str As BE_Full_Nm_Str

 Err_Pos = 35
    'reconnect to the new compacted Back End
     For Each T_Def In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If InStr(T_Def.Name, "MSys") = 0 Then
            T_Def.Connect = ";Database=" & BE_Path_Str & BE_DB_Name_Str
            T_Def.RefreshLink
        End If
     Next T_Def

    ' let backup stay around if compact has corrupted DB
    'Kill BE_Path_Str & "MPD_BEStruct.accdb"

 Err_Pos = 40

    SendKeys "%(FMC)"


'

Exit_BE_Compact:
    Exit Function

Err_BE_Compact:
e_Cnt = e_Cnt + 1
If e_Cnt < 1000 Then
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 3204
            If Err_Pos = 5 Then
                Kill BE_Path_Str & "MPD_BEStruct.accdb"
            End If
            Resume
        Case Else
            Dim Why_Str As String
            Select Case Err_Pos
                Case 5
                    Why_Str = "record Source Disconnect Error"
                Case 10
                    Why_Str = "record Source Disconnect Error"
                Case 15
                    Why_Str = "Previous Backup won't delete"
                Case 20
                    Why_Str = "Tmp Back up of BackEnd datafile failed"
                Case 25
                    Why_Str = "Compac of BackEnd failed"
                Case 30
                    Why_Str = "Rename of compacted BackEnd failed"
                Case 35
                    Why_Str = "Reconnect to BackEnd failed"
            End Select
            If ErrChoice = vbYesNoCancel Then
                ErrMsg = Err.Description & ": " & Str(Err.Number) & vbNewLine & Why_Str & vbNewLine & "Press 'Yes' to resume next;" & vbCrLf & _
                    "'No' to Exit Procedure." & vbCrLf & "or 'Cancel' to break into code"
            Else
                ErrMsg = Err.Description & ": " & Str(Err.Number) & vbNewLine & Why_Str & vbNewLine & "Press 'Yes' to resume next;" & vbCrLf & _
                    "'No' to Exit Procedure."
            End If
   End Select
Else
    Why_Str = "Too Many Errors"
    ErrMsg = Err.Description & ": " & Str(Err.Number) & vbNewLine & Why_Str & vbNewLine & _
        "Press 'OK' to Exit Procedure."
    ErrAns = MsgBox(ErrMsg, _
        vbCritical + vbQuestion + vbOKOnly, "Function: BE_Compact")
    Resume Exit_BE_Compact

 End If

 ErrAns = MsgBox(ErrMsg, _
    vbCritical + vbQuestion + ErrChoice, "Function: BE_Compact")
If ErrAns = vbYes Then
    Resume Next
ElseIf ErrAns = vbCancel Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    Resume
Else
    Resume Exit_BE_Compact
End If
```

Comment: What is the specific error message and what line in the code does it take you to?

Comment: Your code should really be written more modular. Break it up into multiple functions that can take arguments such as the filename instead of hard-coding filenames. Also, your code is difficult to read with all of the underscores and the strange Hungarian notation occurring at the end of your variables.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple splits to get the path.  I would doublecheck that the path is correct as I've copied many Access databases programmatically with FileCopy.